# Select value from text based Postgres field

Tags: sql, postgresql, extract

I would like to extract some information that store in one field.
for example :

`{"Dtl":"{\"title\"campaignId\":\"12345\",\"offerId\":\"67789\"}`

I need the information of campaignid and also offerid

the expected result should be : 12345 and 67789

is there any way to extract that information?

Comment: If that was valid JSON it would be easy.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please post correct json and excpected result

Comment: If you fix your data model, you won't have this problem anymore. Other (future) problems will also be gone or never pop up.

Comment: it will also easier for me, but its my company's data. sorry cannot share the proper detail

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT '{"Dtl": {"campaignId":"12345","offerId":"67789"}}' :: jsonb #> '{Dtl,campaignId}' => "12345"

SELECT '{"Dtl": {"campaignId":"12345","offerId":"67789"}}' :: jsonb #> '{Dtl,offerId}' => "67789"
```

see test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=652b12d9c21b07428f37671882835ac1)